# Facebook Marketing API | Combine breakdowns

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

Is it possible to combine breakdowns using the facebook marketing api? So far I can breakdown my reports by Age, Gender and Region, Country.

But would be nice if I could combine this four breakdowns. Because even having 2 separate reports I will never be able to get the accurate metric values, for example: clicks by Females from 18-25 living in Texas, USA.

I can only have:

- Clicks by females from 18-25
- Clicks from Texas, USA

Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Did you get the key of this problem? I'm stucked in this too..

Answer (score 0):

No! Facebook only allows you to combine selected breakdowns like age and gender which you have already discovered.

Answer (score 0):

you need create 2 diferent consult

$campaignparams['breakdowns'] = ['age','gender'];
$adsetparams ['breakdowns'] =  ['country'];